# "who are"instead of "as"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am plagued by a sentence from journal **Nature**. Though understanding the meaning it conveyed, certainly I could not write in that way. Here is the sentence.

> Focusing evaluation on such inflexible terms leads us (**a**), as scientists at the beginning of our careers (**b**), to adopt utilitarian rather than academic motives.

I view **b** as an infinite attribute to modify **us** in **a**, and I would replace **as** in **b** with **who are**. So I hope you would explain the structure in the original sentence.

Comment: Could you include the link? It's not absolutely vital but at least we can see the original if we wanted. http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v520/n7549_supp/full/520S36a.html

Comment: I can definitely say this without any trepidation the cited passage is perfectly acceptable and grammatical.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that the original sentence is completely correct. However, if I use **who are** rather than **as**, whether the sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: @KikyoKagome: `Who are` certainly wouldn't sound idiomatic(natural)

Comment: _Who are_ would be grammatical here, but very odd-sounding. You can remove _as_ altogether and still have a perfectly fine sentence, though: “Focusing evaluation on such inflexible terms leads us—scientists at the beginning of our careers—to adopt utilitarian rather than academic motives” is perfectly fine. The _as_ clause is a parenthetical statement.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about [this post](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v520/n7549_supp/full/520S36a.html).

*"as"*, here, is used for *"being currently"* and begins a nominal clause, separated from the main clause by commas.

You can move the different clauses of the sentence to understand better :

> Focusing evaluation on such inflexible terms leads us to adopt utilitarian rather than academic motives, *as scientists at the beginning of our careers*.

or

> *As scientists at the beginning of our careers*, focusing evaluation on such inflexible terms leads us to adopt utilitarian rather than academic motives.

or with *"being currently"*

> *Being currently scientists at the beginning of our careers*, focusing evaluation on such inflexible terms leads us to adopt utilitarian rather than academic motives.

Comment: Thank you for telling me the equal meaning _being currently_. However, still confused by the element of _as_. For instance, a sentence from another journal, _We assessed whether patients receiving spinal anesthesia (SPA) **as part of combined spinal-epidural anesthesia (CSE)** more often experience relevant hypotension than patients receiving SPA alone._ The bold element is to modify _spinal anesthesia_ , so whether it is an adverbial or attribute.

Comment: @KikyoKagome I don't understand what you want to understand, the sentence or the "as" usages? Maybe [this page](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as) can help you with "as". The sentence means that patients receiving spinal anesthesia experience more often hypotension when this anesthesia is a part of combined spinal and epidural anesthesia.      *Also, if you think I answered to your question, thank to mark it as accepted, or rephrase it.*

Comment: _As_ is one of the "hard little words" that pop up where you're expecting something else and leave you feeling like you don't quite understand what's going on. It usually means some variety of _be_ has been deleted, somehow, perhaps along with other words, from a subordinate clause, and it links the reduced subordinate clause with what precedes the _as_. Being parenthetical, as @YohannV. points out, it might introduce a reduced non-restrictive relative clause, but putting back _who were_ does not do the job, as you noted.